# Printing specific Beamer overlay slides with Acrobat

Tags: beamer, windows, overlays, printing, acrobat

I want to print specific slides from one frame using Acrobat under Microsoft Windows (I don't have a choice here...).

Specifically, for instance, I want to print the 6th and and 12th slide of my second frame, which corresponds to actual pages 14 and 20 in the PDF.

I have always used Evince on GNU/Linux before, and when I would say "print pages 16 and 20", it would do exactly what I intended. So I tried the same with Acrobat, but it just printed the first slide in the 16th and 20th frames—obviously not at all what I wanted.

Is there a way to con Acrobat into doing exactly what I want from it? Unfortunately, using a different operating system, modifying the LaTeX source, and/or printing both slides separately are not an option.

**Terminlogic clarifications**

It has been pointed out that my use of "slide", "page", etc. was not clear, so I have reworded my question making the following terminologic assumption:

- By "frame", I mean an actual Beamer `\frame`, and the "frame number" is the one that would be output by `\insertframenumber`
- By "slide", I mean a page in the resulting PDF document, therefore a `\frame` with two `\pause`s contains three slides
- By "page", I mean the page number that is shown in parentheses in Acrobat or Evince, or the only page number that is shown in xpdf or GSview—for instance, when I'm looking at the 6th slide in the 2nd frame, I see "2 (14 of 158)", so the 6th slide of the 2nd frame is page 14

Comment: Can you please clarify all the page/slide numbers in your question? It's quite confusing as written... Thanks! :-)

Comment: @darthbith, Thanks for pointing that out. I have tried to look up what terminology is normally used with Beamer and reworded my question accordingly.

Comment: Quick fix is to navigate to the page and just use the option to print the current page. (Not great if you do this often but useful if you urgently need 1 or 2 slides.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a setting that's buried in the Adobe Reader preferences. According to [this message on Adobe's forums](https://forums.adobe.com/message/5669609) you need to disable logical page numbering. That's under "Edit->Preferences" (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>), in the "Categories" on the left choose "Page Display", then under the "Page Content and Information" header, uncheck "Use logical page numbers", which is the third checkbox in the left column. Apparently the option is the same for at least Adobe Readers X and XI.