# How to print complete frames in pdf, not slides

Tags: beamer, printing, acrobat

I have a pdf which comes from a Beamer presentation, but I don't have access to the code of the original presentation. Each frame is made of several slides as explained in a similar question:  [Printing specific Beamer overlay slides with Acrobat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232533/printing-specific-beamer-overlay-slides-with-acrobat).

If a list is made of 5 bullet points, each separated by a pause command, I would like to print the whole list in one page instead of 5 times. In other words, I need to print only the last slide of each frame.

I am using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC and made sure that Edit->Preferences->Page Display->"Use logical page numbers" is checked. However, the only effect is that the page number I write in the printing options now corresponds to the frame number instead of the slide number. Then, once I write the frame number, all the slides corresponding to that frame are still printed.

Is there an option for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You could use a graphics editor and crop off the slide you want, then export the cropped image.

Comment: Use pdfarranger https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger --- it's a nice utility to have around if you use PDF files (and who don't?)

Comment: @Zarko thank you!

Comment: @JohnKormylo I apologize if the question was unclear, but the single list was only an example. Actually there are hundreds of slides and I was wondering if there is a general way to print the last slide of each frame.